# simple question on asp net profile

Tags: asp.net

i believe this is a simple question but i can't figure out myself. In the aspnet profile there is propertynames column with value [value]:*:*: (e.g. OfficeKey:S:0:1:)

Does anyone know what the ":S:0:1:" is? How can I read it?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means it's a **String**, which starts at position **0** in the PropertyValuesString field, and is **1** character long.

Have a read of http://pretzelsteelersfan.blogspot.com/2007/03/get-aspnet-profile-properties-from-sql.html if you want to do your own manipulation of the fields in SQL.

Comment: ok.. how about updating,deleting, and inserting into aspnet_profile?

Comment: If you want your fields easily accessible through SQL and you have the flexibility to change providers, you could try the Table Profile Provider: http://www.asp.net/downloads/sandbox/table-profile-provider-samples

Comment: @user384080 - If you're using standard `SqlProfileProvider` profiles it's almost certainly better to use the standard functions to manipulate them, rather than to try to do it yourself. But NightOwl888's link looks like it might provide an interesting alternative.